# Manually resolve a dependency in Spring [Boot]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

This seems like it should be trivial, but both Google and StackOverflow seem to be just as uncooperative as Spring docs (or I just don't know where to look).

My Spring Boot application needs to manually instantiate certain classes. Some of the classes have dependencies, so I can't use `.newInstance()`; instead, I figure I need to ask Spring to give me the instance from its DI container. Something like

```java
Class<? extends Interface> className = service.getClassName();
Interface x = SpringDI.getInstance(className);
```

But I can't seem to find any way of doing this. What should I do?

**EDIT**

Class names are resolved dynamically, I have updated my sample pseuido-code to reflect that.

Comment: isn't there spring context get bean function?

Comment: @DmytroGrynets yes there is. I have just provided him with an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about autowiring the `ApplicationContext` in the component in which you want to instantiate those classes? As `ApplicationContext` implements the `BeanFactory` interface, you can call the `getBean()` method.

Something like:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

[...]

applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean(clazz_name);
```

I am not sure why you would want to do this, tho, as it defies the purpose of using Spring. (you can just not use Spring but use Java's reflection API)

Please refer to this part of the JavaDocs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html

Comment: I assumed I had to use spring since Spring is the one that processes all the `Component` and `Service` annotations and thus knows which classes are available for DI. How could this be accomplished with just Java?

Comment: You will need to learn about Java's reflection API. Essentially, that allows you to instantiate classes based on their names, analyze classes at runtime to find out the name of methods and invoke methods on an object based on the method name (this is over-simplified). Spring uses reflection underneath and provides an abstraction for it using the ApplicationContext (more correctly put, the BeanFactory). Just as Spring leverages reflection, you can do that as well.

Comment: In that case, I don't see the benefit of writing the whole class lookup if it's already implemented by Spring and simplified to a one-line command — which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Comment: Note also `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(className)` method (see [AutowireCapableBeanFactory doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#createBean-java.lang.Class-)). It allows to instantiate beans which weren't registered in appContext.